# Can't load TestbedHarnessEnvironment or how to click on MatRadioButton

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

In my Angular 10 application for one of my unit tests I need to click on MatRadioButton.

Here https://material.angular.io/guide/using-component-harnesses I found instructions how to do it, but the moment I add this line:

```
loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
```

I start getting error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
> at 
> at Function.loader (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/testing/testbed.js:589:1)
> at http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/src/app/maps/maps.component.spec.ts:55:40
> at 
> at http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:74:1
> at new ZoneAwarePromise (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:960:1)
> at __awaiter (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:70:1)
> at UserContext. (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/src/app/maps/maps.component.spec.ts:48:26)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
> at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke
> (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:292:1)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:363:1)

Googling did not help other than indicate some bug that was going to be fixed (https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/angular/components/21632/764975917).

How to resolve this? Or how to click on the MatRadioButton? Should I just simulate click via DOM using native elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/angular/components/21632/764975917 has a good answer:

> The unit tests fail when the harness loader is created in an async
> beforeEach and the TS target is ES2018. StackBlitz Demo
>
> There are three solutions to this problem.
>
> 1. Move the call to TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader to the it function (demo).
> 2. Use waitForAsync in the beforeEach instead of an async function (demo).
> 3. Change the target to ES2016 (demo).

Though, to use one of its suggestion (use waitForAsync instead of async) requires upgrade of Angular to v11.